# Problema com scrollbar interna

Tags: html, css

Em certas resoluções(menores) a barra de scroll na div "contatos" funciona perfeitamente, porém, em outras elas fica sobreposta pela conteúdo a sua esquerda.

Com a resolução normal fica da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A borda e a div de cima sobrepõe a scrollbar, mas em uma tela menor, que a pagina ficaria com uma barra lateral geral, a scrollbar funciona perfeitamente

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.mensagens {
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 80%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #00000080;
}

.mensagens .contatos {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.mensagens .contatos::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
}
 
.mensagens .contatos::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888;
}

.mensagens .contatos .pesquisa {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    z-index: -1;
}

.mensagens .contatos .pesquisa input {
    height: 30px;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    outline: none;
}

.mensagens .contatos .pesquisa button {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #5969FF;
    color: #fefefe;
    border: none;
    margin-right: 5px;
    outline: none;
}

.mensagens .contatos .conversas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.mensagens .contatos .conversas .contato {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}

.mensagens .contatos .conversas .contato .img {
    width: 20%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.mensagens .contatos .conversas .contato .img img {
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.mensagens .contatos .conversas .contato .info {
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.mensagens .contatos .conversas .contato .info .nome {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.mensagens .contatos .conversas .contato .info .texto {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666;
}

.mensagens .contatos .conversas .contato .horario {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mensagens">
    <div class="contatos">
        <div class="pesquisa">
            <input type="text" name="pesquisa" id="pesquisa" placeholder="Pesquisar...">
            <button><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="conversas">
            <div class="contato">
                <div class="img"><img src="https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/1638a4766b1125889a4b8276881ee1c9/L0KzQYm3VcA5N5DBiZH0aYP2gLBuTgV0baMye9H2cIX3dcO0ifNwdqQyiAt8dHXwPbTvif5me5Yyj9t3ZD33ecXzhb1kd516hdC2NXHpQYW5VBZlO5JnTKo3M0e7RIa8VccyPWM6T6g5NkO8SIeATwBvbz==/kisspng-user-computer-icons-system-chinese-wind-title-column-5af1427fd3ab48.378455571525760639867.png"></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <span class="nome">Anom</span>
                    <span class="texto"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Opa</span>
                </div>
                <div class="horario"><span>10:15</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="contato">
                <div class="img"><img src="https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/1638a4766b1125889a4b8276881ee1c9/L0KzQYm3VcA5N5DBiZH0aYP2gLBuTgV0baMye9H2cIX3dcO0ifNwdqQyiAt8dHXwPbTvif5me5Yyj9t3ZD33ecXzhb1kd516hdC2NXHpQYW5VBZlO5JnTKo3M0e7RIa8VccyPWM6T6g5NkO8SIeATwBvbz==/kisspng-user-computer-icons-system-chinese-wind-title-column-5af1427fd3ab48.378455571525760639867.png"></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <span class="nome">Anom</span>
                    <span class="texto"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Opa</span>
                </div>
                <div class="horario"><span>10:15</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="contato">
                <div class="img"><img src="https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/1638a4766b1125889a4b8276881ee1c9/L0KzQYm3VcA5N5DBiZH0aYP2gLBuTgV0baMye9H2cIX3dcO0ifNwdqQyiAt8dHXwPbTvif5me5Yyj9t3ZD33ecXzhb1kd516hdC2NXHpQYW5VBZlO5JnTKo3M0e7RIa8VccyPWM6T6g5NkO8SIeATwBvbz==/kisspng-user-computer-icons-system-chinese-wind-title-column-5af1427fd3ab48.378455571525760639867.png"></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <span class="nome">Anom</span>
                    <span class="texto"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Opa</span>
                </div>
                <div class="horario"><span>10:15</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="contato">
                <div class="img"><img src="https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/1638a4766b1125889a4b8276881ee1c9/L0KzQYm3VcA5N5DBiZH0aYP2gLBuTgV0baMye9H2cIX3dcO0ifNwdqQyiAt8dHXwPbTvif5me5Yyj9t3ZD33ecXzhb1kd516hdC2NXHpQYW5VBZlO5JnTKo3M0e7RIa8VccyPWM6T6g5NkO8SIeATwBvbz==/kisspng-user-computer-icons-system-chinese-wind-title-column-5af1427fd3ab48.378455571525760639867.png"></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <span class="nome">Anom</span>
                    <span class="texto"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Opa</span>
                </div>
                <div class="horario"><span>10:15</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="contato">
                <div class="img"><img src="https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/1638a4766b1125889a4b8276881ee1c9/L0KzQYm3VcA5N5DBiZH0aYP2gLBuTgV0baMye9H2cIX3dcO0ifNwdqQyiAt8dHXwPbTvif5me5Yyj9t3ZD33ecXzhb1kd516hdC2NXHpQYW5VBZlO5JnTKo3M0e7RIa8VccyPWM6T6g5NkO8SIeATwBvbz==/kisspng-user-computer-icons-system-chinese-wind-title-column-5af1427fd3ab48.378455571525760639867.png"></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <span class="nome">Anom</span>
                    <span class="texto"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Opa</span>
                </div>
                <div class="horario"><span>10:15</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="contato">
                <div class="img"><img src="https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/1638a4766b1125889a4b8276881ee1c9/L0KzQYm3VcA5N5DBiZH0aYP2gLBuTgV0baMye9H2cIX3dcO0ifNwdqQyiAt8dHXwPbTvif5me5Yyj9t3ZD33ecXzhb1kd516hdC2NXHpQYW5VBZlO5JnTKo3M0e7RIa8VccyPWM6T6g5NkO8SIeATwBvbz==/kisspng-user-computer-icons-system-chinese-wind-title-column-5af1427fd3ab48.378455571525760639867.png"></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <span class="nome">Anom</span>
                    <span class="texto"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Opa</span>
                </div>
                <div class="horario"><span>10:15</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="contato">
                <div class="img"><img src="https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/1638a4766b1125889a4b8276881ee1c9/L0KzQYm3VcA5N5DBiZH0aYP2gLBuTgV0baMye9H2cIX3dcO0ifNwdqQyiAt8dHXwPbTvif5me5Yyj9t3ZD33ecXzhb1kd516hdC2NXHpQYW5VBZlO5JnTKo3M0e7RIa8VccyPWM6T6g5NkO8SIeATwBvbz==/kisspng-user-computer-icons-system-chinese-wind-title-column-5af1427fd3ab48.378455571525760639867.png"></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <span class="nome">Anom</span>
                    <span class="texto"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Opa</span>
                </div>
                <div class="horario"><span>10:15</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="contato">
                <div class="img"><img src="https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/1638a4766b1125889a4b8276881ee1c9/L0KzQYm3VcA5N5DBiZH0aYP2gLBuTgV0baMye9H2cIX3dcO0ifNwdqQyiAt8dHXwPbTvif5me5Yyj9t3ZD33ecXzhb1kd516hdC2NXHpQYW5VBZlO5JnTKo3M0e7RIa8VccyPWM6T6g5NkO8SIeATwBvbz==/kisspng-user-computer-icons-system-chinese-wind-title-column-5af1427fd3ab48.378455571525760639867.png"></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <span class="nome">Anom</span>
                    <span class="texto"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Opa</span>
                </div>
                <div class="horario"><span>10:15</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="contato">
                <div class="img"><img src="https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/1638a4766b1125889a4b8276881ee1c9/L0KzQYm3VcA5N5DBiZH0aYP2gLBuTgV0baMye9H2cIX3dcO0ifNwdqQyiAt8dHXwPbTvif5me5Yyj9t3ZD33ecXzhb1kd516hdC2NXHpQYW5VBZlO5JnTKo3M0e7RIa8VccyPWM6T6g5NkO8SIeATwBvbz==/kisspng-user-computer-icons-system-chinese-wind-title-column-5af1427fd3ab48.378455571525760639867.png"></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <span class="nome">Anom</span>
                    <span class="texto"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Opa</span>
                </div>
                <div class="horario"><span>10:15</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/luan-peil/pen/xNYYMW

Comment: Cara teria como vc adicionar uma imagem na sua pergunta de como está ficando ai. E explicar melhor qual comportamento que vc quer ou como vc quer que fique o resultado final?

Comment: @hugocsl, colocado as imagens

Comment: Me parece problema de renderização do próprio browser... mas não tenho certeza... não consegui simular o problema aqui. Vc sabe que essa barra só funciona no Chrome né?